# Can I create trigger on a view?

Tags: sql, oracle10g, sql-view, database-trigger

```
Table APPLICANTS        
APP_ID    PARTNER_ID APP_STATUS_ID
226217012   1018      10
226217472   1018      14
258337939   1023      14
226217512   1018      14
258337919   1023      14
226217445   1018      14
226217487   1018      14
226217412   1018      14
226217502   1018      14
226000476   1018      11
```

I need to create view of this table with above field. like  APPLICANTS_v  with same field

```
 APP_ID    PARTNER_ID  APP_STATUS_ID
226217012   1018           10
226217472   1018           14
258337939   1023           14
226217512   1018           14
258337919   1023           14
226217445   1018           14
226217487   1018           14
226217412   1018           14
226217502   1018           14
226000476   1018           11
```

I have another table (blank table) fields given below

```
CREATE TABLE "STATUS_CHANGE" 
(   APP_ID NUMBER, 
    PARTNER_ID NUMBER, 
    OLD_APP_STATUS_ID NUMBER(3,0),
    NEW_APP_STATUS_ID NUMBER(3,0),
    MODIFIED_ON DATE
 ) ;
```

I want to insert in STATUS_CHANGE only those records, when anyone updates the field APPLICANT_STATUS_ID in "APPLICANTS" Like

```
update APPLICANTS set APP_STATUS_ID=9
where APP_STATUS_ID=10
and APPLICANT_ID=226217012  
AND PARTNER_ID=1018
```

As update this table value, that time that record inserted with new
Or old value with current time in table STATUS_CHANGE like :-

```
 APPL_ID PARTNER_ID  OLD_APP_STATUS_ID NEW_APP_STATUS_ID  MODIFIED_ON

 22621701    1018        10                       9       28/05/2015
```

Can I create a trigger on the APPLICANTS_v view to insert a STATUS_CHANGE record when update value in APPLICANTS table?

Comment: Please make an effort to format your question correctly. As it is, it is hard to read.

Comment: thank you @ germi , I am tried to formatted the code now you can read it properly so please suggest its need full.

Comment: Use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger. Details including an example are in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm#sthref7917